# Vim Plugin to Resolve a Member Function More Efficiently Using Ctags

Tags: vim, ctags

Say I have N class' defined as:

```
 1 class Bar0
 2 {
 3 public:
 4     void func();
 5 };
 6
 7 void Bar0::func()
 8 {}
 9 
10 class Bar1
11 {
12 public:
13     void func()
14 };
15
16 void Bar1::func()
17 {}
```

Say I am using ctags, my tags file is sorted and I am using it with vim. When I place my cursor over `func` on line 13 and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. This will/could take me to the definition of `Bar0`'s member function `func` on line 7 because its lexicographical ordering comes before `Bar1`'s. To get around that I could use <kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and this would open a separate buffer where I could search for the one I want. However, lets say `func` is a virtual member function that is in about 20 classes. At that point I could also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> with `:tp` and `:tn` to shuffle through all 20. Thus, my question. Is there a plugin or code I can add to my .vimrc, such that I can use it in conjunction with ctags to resolve member functions based on the scope of its class faster than a linear search through all possible options? I would like to stay away from plugins like [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags), I wrap ctags results in order to display them, search among them (with `/`), filter them, etc.

Unfortunately, I only use ctags which doesn't understand C++: it won't be able to know which overload a call site is referring to.

That's where [vim-clang](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-clang) and [clang-indexer](https://github.com/LucHermitte/clang_indexer) came into the equation. I haven't spent time in them in ages. I'm not even sure clang-indexer still compiles with the latest version of clang. The idea is to built a code database, and to extract the real context from the current code in order to correctly identify overloads and so on. The last time I used, it had troubles sometimes to identify the current context.

Note that [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) should be able to jump to a function declaration, and in the best case scenario to a function definition, that is in the same translation unit as the current file.

Comment: I would assume that building the index is fairly expensive and might slow down vim on open similar to intellisense in Visual Studio if using clang-indexer? Ill have to take a look. Also I am currently using YouCompleteMe, but am noticing it doesn't function as well on large code basses. Current job has not modularized their components as well as they should of.

Comment: Building, or more precisely maintaining, the index doesn't have to be extensive. The first time requires to index the whole project. then, only the file that change. I must admit I don't remember clang-indexer internals. ^^'