# Vim: How to go to the declaration of a C++ method using ctags

Tags: vim, ctags

How do I jump to the declaration of a C++ method instead of the definition using `:tag` or `C-]`? I tried

```
ctags * --C++-kinds=+p
```

to generate the tags file but `:tselect` still does not list any declarations, only definitions. The header files are hpp files and source files are cpp files, all in the same directory.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950419/2734140) but it does not answer my question, except for a comment from where I got the above idea (`--<LANG>-kinds`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the following options: `--c++-kinds=+pf --fields=+imaSft --extras=+q`. Among many other things, I see function definitions and function declarations.

I handle everything automatically in [a plugin I've been maintaining](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags) for quite some time.

On the same subject, see also:

- [Jump to function definition in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635770/jump-to-function-definition-in-vim/)
- [Vim Plugin to Resolve a Member Function More Efficiently Using Ctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729698/vim-plugin-to-resolve-a-member-function-more-efficiently-using-ctags/)

BTW, I highly recommend using universal-ctags (the maintained fork) instead of exhuberant ctags (the venerable and unmaintained project) when trying to generate tags for C++.

Comment: Does this work only with universal-ctags? I tried this with exuberant but `extras` is not supported. I tried without it (only kinds and fields) but I still don't get declarations. Thanks for pointing me to universal-ctags, though.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, It used to be `extra` with ex-ctags.

Comment: Great, thanks! `--c++-kinds=+pf  --extra=+q` was enough to make it jump to prototypes first and to display prototypes when I do `g C-]`. Is there a way to keep prototype tags but have it jump to definitions first?